# Preloading fonts using link not working on Android

Tags: html, preload

I've tried including fonts in my page using the following code as this performs better than the using the CSS approach according to Google's Lighthouse. Unfortunately, doing so, Android does not see/find the font and hence uses a fallback. Everything works well on Windows desktop. What am I doing wrong? How can I debug this?

```
<link rel="preload" href="/templates/fonts/Roboto.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, Android does not support .woff2 fonts.
You could convert to .ttf and that should fix the issue.
Regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @milen-nenkov I will test it out, but bear in mind that the woff2 font is read by Android when I include it vis CSS. It's only when using the <link> tag that it doesn't work

Comment: According to this document Android supports woff2 fonts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face